# 'drush field-create' with type INTEGER from command line? drupal (ver 7.22) | drush (ver 6)

Tags: drush

tried to manage fields of tpye 'int' with drush (batch), without success!

working:
drush field-create user streetname,text,text_textfield --entity_type=user

not working:
drush field-create user streetnumber,integer,text_textfield --entity_type=user

workaround:
drush field-create streetnumber --entity_type=user
-> offers interactive dialog only 
Field name: ... 
Choose a field type ... 
Choose a widget ...
--> '_http://default//fields/streetnumber'

Maybe there's another way to provide data, like

- drush field-create user streetnumber < inputfile ??
- drush field-create user streetnumber < 'fieldname_XYZ','6','1' ??

any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

for an integer field type, try this :

```
drush field-create user streetnumber, number_integer, number_textfield
```

Or :

```
drush field-create user streetnumber, number_integer
```

(because you can ommit the widget type and the default one will be used).

If you are looking for the name of another field type, create the field in the admin panel, then look in your database, in table field_config, you will find it in the type column.

Comment: here is a complete list of fields: https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/api/field-api/field-types-and-settings